# Android Game Development: Handler/Runnable not repeating action

Tags: java, android, eclipse, handler, runnable

I'm very inexperienced in Android development but right now I'm trying to develop a game using Android's tools in Eclipse. It's a simple game. On the screen I have areas where the user touches to move a character. I used the Runnable/Handler to try to repeat the action of the character moving in the direction corresponding to the touch area. However, every time I touch the area, it only moves the character down a little.

Here's my code.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         protagonist.moveDown();
    }
};
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int touchX = (int)event.getX();
    int touchY = (int)event.getY();
    if(down.contains(touchX,touchY)) {
         boolean mBooleanIsPressed = true;
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
            mBooleanIsPressed = true;
        }

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(mBooleanIsPressed) {
                mBooleanIsPressed = false;
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Down is the touch area that makes the character move down. What's wrong with my code or what can I do to fix it and make it better?

Thank you.